# My mergesort function is spitting out 0's instead of ordering my list

Tags: c++, mergesort

I'm trying to make a Mergesort function and can't seem to understand why my list is printing out "00000100000". I have a feeling it might be my auxiliary array that i'm passing through, but i'd like to keep it in my code if possible. Here is my code:

```
void merge(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int leftStart = low;
    int rightStart = mid+1;
    int auxIndex = low;
    int start = low;

while(leftStart<=mid && rightStart<= high)
{

    if(arr[leftStart]>=arr[rightStart])
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = arr[rightStart];
        auxIndex++;
        rightStart++;
    }
    else
        aux[auxIndex] = arr[leftStart];
        auxIndex++;
        leftStart++;
}
if(leftStart>mid)
{
    for(;rightStart<=high; rightStart++)
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = arr[rightStart];
    }
}
if(rightStart>high)
{
    for(;leftStart<=high; leftStart++)
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = arr[rightStart];
    }
}
for(; start <= high; start++)
    arr[start]=aux[start];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low<high)
    {
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    mergeSort(arr, aux, low, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, aux, mid+1, high);
    merge(arr,aux, low, mid, high);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int arr[20]={6,4,3,2,1,7,8,9,5,6,7,5};
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    cout<<arr[i];
int aux[20];
mergeSort(arr, aux, 0, 12);
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    cout<<arr[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I take it using `std::merge()` is out of the question for making this entire problem just go away.

Answer (score 1):

Run your program under `valgrind` or an equivalent analysis tool.  You will find that there are straightforward errors in your code related to array accesses.

Comment: Valgrind may not find problems because his arrays are 20 entries despite only trying to sort 12 entries' worth of data. Perhaps he was trying to paper over a stack smashing issue?